# What's the catch with these JFETs?

Tags: rf, analog, jfet, low-noise-amplifier

I'm designing a low-noise, high-bandwidth (100 MHz) pre-amp using JFETs. The choice for JFETs was because it needs to operate with large source impedances (>10 kΩ).

I spent a while looking for a suitable JFET (high g, low input C, good noise-figure). I came across ones from CEL (for example, the CE3520K3 ([datasheet](http://www.cel.com/pdf/datasheets/CE3520K3.pdf), [home page](http://www.cel.com/parts.do?command=load&idRootPart=2600)) with g = 50 mS , NF = 0.5). They don't specify input capacitance, but it must be sub-pF given the operational frequencies. What's the catch? The datasheet does specify large gate currents, so current shot noise will be high. Does anyone have experience working with such devices?

Comment: Datasheet says "s-parameters are available on the website " and indeed they are. Instead of citing an input capacitance at specific test conditions they provide scattering parameters so you can model the input impedance for your application.

Comment: s-parms start at 2GHz no use

Comment: Use the 2GHz s-param value, and on the Smith chart proceed to decompose the Z into real and imaginary (capacitive) component values.

Comment: What is the BW at 100MHz

Comment: Having read the comments to @SunnyskyguyEE75's answer, I can say that this wonderful HFET (Heterojunction FET) is not an optimal prestige for a preamplifier. Years ago, we built a photodiode preamplifier (the photodiode was an Hamamatsu APD) with 60 MHz BW, with a FET input stage: we obtained the best results from a BF998 (a silicon dual gate MOSFET) and discarded two GaAs device (a CF739 and a CFY25) just because their high leakage current. High source impedance, high bandwidth preamplifiers require *lowest input capacitance* **and** *the lowest leakage (bias) current* reachable.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Although they don't specify Cgs, I would expect it to be around 2 pF and 0.4typ ~10μA max is not bad

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I agree it is not bad at all, but if you look at the BF998 that figures are respectively \$2.5\mathrm{pF}\$ and \$50\mathrm{nA}\$ maximum, therefore the Johnson noise is at least \$10\mathrm{dB}\$: that was the key parameter which make our design succeed.

Comment: I've used JFETs in stuff, not my favorite. For a linear amplifiers they have a narrow linear range ~1-2v. Also their depletion mode so you need to bias the gate negatively. If it were me I would search high and dry for a high BW opamp to use to buffer the impedance.

Answer (score 2):

There are no catches (lol) Only Specs

The s-parameters start at 2GHz

```
CEL
! CE3520K3
! N-channel HJ-FET
! Vds = 2 V Id = 6 mA
# Hz S  MA   R 50
!      f            S11               S21               S12               S22
!    Hz        MAG       ANG       MAG       ANG        MAG        ANG       MAG       ANG
2000000000 0.98035944 -29.159311 4.3293347 149.29152 0.02862794 67.64743 0.65920687 -24.487707
```

## What is the purpose?

In the meantime, WHAT's ALL THIS STUFF ABOUT ...?

## GaAs pHEMT JFETs

[image]

It's just balancing act

[image]

A delicate balancing act.

[image]

Just start with good Design Specs,  including DFM, DFT , then perform DVT and if passes all tests. Congrats, Its Perfect.
[image]

or startover until it passes your design specs.

[image]

Or do it right the 1st time with better specs.

[***REF***](https://www.nxp.com/files/training_pdf/WBNR_LNA.pdf)

---

[20 Years ago HP R&D came up with this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/98feb/feb98a5.pdf)

To address the growing handset power amplifier needs for the emerging
Personal Communications Services (PCS) markets, a 3-volt, single-supply,
enhancement-mode pseudomorphic high-electron-mobility transistor (E-PHEMT)
has been developed.

The device exhibits +33dBm output power and 65% drain efficiency at 1.88 GHz.

Consider a state of the art FET buffered Differential Probe specs
[image]

[image]

Using [MGF4919G](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-Original-MGF4919G-SUPER-LOW-NOISE-/280897340734?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4166c9453e)
[image]
[image]
[REF](http://www.ntms.org/eme/presentations/w5lua/G4DDK_Getting%20the%20most%20from%20your%20G4DDK%20VLNA%20-%20Dall.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the info, it very helpful. The design already has a resonant front end, with pretty much the exact the values you suggest. The task is to make a resonant photodiode amplifier which can be shot-noise limited <pA/sqrt(Hz) level to detect a very weak AM light source. Initially we tried using low-noise FET op-amps, but found they had too much current noise at high frequencies.  We are testing some designs to see if we can do better with just a common source or cascode. We will see how I get on...

Comment: Where are your specs? Is this something fancy like  a  Interferometric Gravitational wave Detector?

Comment: It is a one off devices for research (sadly not LIGO, but they have some nice papers on it), so cost/size/power constraints don't come in to it. All I care about is being photon shot noise limited for powers about 10 uW. My photodiode has a sensitivity of 0.35 A/W (I have to work @ 450 nm  as the end application is spectroscopy), so if I want the Johnson–Nyquist current noise to be below the photon-shot noise I need a source resistance to be >10 kΩ. The modulation frequency has to >50 MHz.

Comment: that's doable in Ga-As BJT's

Comment: How does 0.65dB Noise figure sound at 100MHz ?

Comment: Or do you need 0.5dB Noise figure?

Comment: InGaAs from MItsubishi is the best.  MGF4919G

Comment: Noise Figure requires a SOURCE IMPEDANCE, usually 50 ohms.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  how would you approach this problem with high impedance?